# How to draw geometries of a shapefile on a user control using C#?

Tags: geometry, draw, shapefile

I am trying to write an application to visualize shapefile on a .net form without using any external SDK. I have successfully written the code to read a shapefile. Now I am unable to get the GDI+ trick to draw the geometries to the user control effectively.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide more information about shapefile format ?

Comment: Shapefile mainly consists of three files shp, shx and dbf.
The geometry information are stored in .shp file. The specification of shapefile can be obtain from www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Comment: Do you know they are convertible to ordinary image formats ?

Comment: The shapefile geometries are simply points, lines and polygons. The line and polygon geometries are again made up using the points. I am able to read the coordinates/points from the geometry. I just need to write methods like:

public void DrawPoint(Point p)
{
//Write GDI+ code to draw a point on user control.
}

public void DrawLine(Line l)
{
//Write GDI+ code to draw a line on user control.
}

public void DrawPolygon(Polygon p)
{
//Write GDI+ code to draw a polygon on user control.
}

Comment: OK, you should Graphics object of a UserControl, I paste it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Graphics object of a UserControl( generally a Control ) to draw points, lines, etc on it. This will be useful if you can obtain point information from shapefile. Use following links to make it work.
[Drawing with Brush on UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150079/drawing-with-brush-on-usercontrol) and
[Drawing a Point on a Custom UserControl](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/f681eef0-645d-48a0-bfb9-8c0473ebf974)

This is an example :

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawPolygon( ... ) ;
```

Comment: I managed to write a code like below.

private void AddLine(Line line)
{
Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue);

pen.Width = 2;

path.AddLine(line.Points[0].AsPointF(), line.Points[1].AsPointF());

g.DrawPath(pen, path);

pen.Dispose();
}

Now the problem is that, the graphics created is not stable. During runtime, if another window comes above the user control, the graphics goes away. What could be the problem?

Comment: You should put the code inside the paint event. You should override OnPaint() method and put the code of lines in ti. Whenever window needs to be repainted this method will be called. This is like paint() method in OpenGL, DirectX, etc.